# Can rsync adjust sym-links to reflect their new location?

Tags: linux, rsync

I have a directory tree that has internal, absolute sym-links, and I want to rsync it with a different disk. My problem is sym-links. After I rsync, the sym-links on the new disk all point to the original location on the old disk. I need this to change.

Obviously, I could write a script that would traverse the newly sync'd directory and "fix-up" the sym-links, but this seems like a pretty universal problem; one which would already be solved in rsync, itself.

Is there a way to "edit" sym-link targets? For example,

> rsync ... -s "/mnt/src:/mnt/dst"

might mean,

> If you find a sym-link that starts "/mnt/src", then change it to "/mnt/dst".

rsync already knows how to restrict operations to a specific filesystem, so my question is, "Can rsync sync two different file systems maintaining the individual semantics of each separate filesystem, meaning sym-links to a file in one should point to the corresponding file in the other?".

Thanks for the help,

Chris.

Comment: I think the answer is no. If you want to fix the absolute symbolic links look for the `symlinks` command, but you would need to do it where the links resolve correctly first.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/593479/rsync-update-symlinks-pointing-to-same-directory#:~:text=Unfortunately%20it%20is%20not%20possible,symlinks%20in%20your%20source%20folder.